# Validation using on[Property]Changing methods of EF4

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, validation

I have a WPF application,  with a data layer made by EF4.
On one of the screens, I display a container (entit name: master), which contains multiple elemenbts (entity name: project).

The master has a status which can be open or closed (set by the user), but can't be closed if all its projects are not closed.

I used the partial class in entity framewok to do this:

```
public partial class Master
{
    partial void OnStatusIdChanging(int value)
    {
        if (value == 2)  // Changing status to closed.
        {
            // Must check if all projects are closed.
            if (this.Projects.Any(e => e.StatusId == 1))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("All the underlying projects must be closed to set the master'status to closed.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is bound like this in the xaml:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding MasterStatusTypes}" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentMaster.StatusId, Mode=TwoWay}">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

But I don't know ho to prevent the change in the combobox.  What I'd like to do is display a messagebox when this error occurs, and set the old value back until it can validate, but I can't find how to get this message, or replace the value.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using the [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) interface for any validation, since WPF is built to use it. You can then set your bindings like this to use built-in validation:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentMaster.StatusId, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" ... />
```